# Using .htaccess to redirect prefix to folder

Tags: .htaccess

in .htaccess i have already :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*.html)(\?.*)?$ /scripts/engine.php?path=$1/$2 [QSA,L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /scripts/engine.php?path=/$1/ [QSA,L,PT]
RewriteRule ^$ /scripts/engine.php?path=/ [QSA,L,PT]
```

i want to add redirect of

```
<prefix>.<domain>.com to <prefix>.<domain>.com/<folder>
```

how can I do it while keeping the previous rules

------ Thanks to whom answered

thanks 
it works when put in this order

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^prefix1\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/edt_oracle_awr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/edt_mysql_slow/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/edt_sybase_checkmep/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://prefix2.domain.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*.html)(\?.*)?$ /scripts/engine.php?path=$1/$2 [QSA,L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /scripts/engine.php?path=/$1/ [QSA,L,PT]
RewriteRule ^$ /scripts/engine.php?path=/ [QSA,L,PT]
```

how to hide redirection ? the browser will show prefix1.domain.com without looping

Comment: Can you clarify what the question is? There are two things in mod_rewrite: redirects `[R]` and internal rewrites (without `[R]`). What is currently happening and what do you want to happen?

Comment: actually after redirecting the browser shows in address bar  http://prefix2.domain.com/folder

is there an option to keep it prefix1.domain.com ?

Comment: ??? What is the original url. What is the url that should be shown in the address bar? What is the page that should be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

In mod_rewrite there are two concepts, named redirect and internal rewrite.

**Redirect**

Mod_rewrite can redirect a request from a to b. This is indicated by the `[R]` flag behind the rule. If the user requests, for example `http://foo.example.com`, you can redirect it to `http://bar.example.com`. What this does, is that you tell the client that the page has been moved to `http://foo.com` and that they should redo the request to that url. It'll show `http://foo.com` in the address bar.

**Internal rewrite**

Mod_rewrite can also internally rewrite url's if the file you want to show is in the same filesystem. This is indicated by the *absence* of the `[R]` flag. If the user requests `http://foo.example.com`, you internally rewrite it to a file that could also be reached by `http://bar.example.com`, assuming that both `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` are in the same filesystem. This would show `http://foo.example.com` in the address bar, but would actually show a file that can also be reached by `http://bar.example.com`. Please note that search engines will believe they are 2 different pages with exactly the same content, and might penalize your website for this.

**Your case**

In your case you seem to be requesting an internal rewrite and not a redirect like the title suggests. Without the structure of the filesystem I can't really test anything, but something like this should suffice.

```
RewriteRule ^path/to/subdomain1/(.*)$ path/to/subdomain2/$1 [L]
```

Comment: how to get errorDocument to work when use prefix in the URL address?

Comment: ErrorDocument is a directory-context type of directive, but it probably should be put inside the virtualhost instead. Consider asking a new question where you clearly outline what you have done and what you are trying to accomplish.